# SDL_Fillrect segmentation fault / struct inside struct with pointer confusion

Tags: c, struct, malloc, sdl

Firstly I want to say that I'm not a professional c programmer 
and  with that out of the  way, i'll get right into my problem.

So i have these 2 structs:

```
struct hitPointData{
    int size;
    int maxHp;
    int currentHp;
    SDL_Rect healthBarCurrent;
    SDL_Rect healthBarMax;
    SDL_Surface* healthSurface;
    SDL_Texture* healthTexture;
};

struct PlayableCharacter{
    SDL_Rect playerBox;
    int xSpeed;
    int ySpeed;
    struct hitPointData playerHp;
};
```

And the problem i have is that  i get  a  segmentation fault in this function call:

```
SDL_FillRect(player->playerHp.healthSurface,
             NULL, // Not actually supposed to be NULL, just here until i get fillrect working properly
             SDL_MapRGB(player->playerHp.healthSurface->format,255,0,0));
```

i think it might have something to do with the surface/surface->format because when i do:

```
player->playerHp.healthSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,32,16,4,0,255,255,0);
```

i dont get the segmentation error however Fillrect returns an error code saying that the format is not supported.

Also this is how i initialize the player:

```
struct PlayableCharacter *player = malloc(sizeof(struct PlayableCharacter));
```

I know segmentation error basically means you're writing outside your allowed memory and i suspect i have to malloc somewhere but im  not  really sure where or how.

Any help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: `malloc` does not initialise the memory it provides. So `player->playerHp.healthSurface` has an arbitrary value that will cause problems when you try to dereference it. If the struct contains pointers, each one must be initialised too. But when you do initialise it, you get a different kind of error, but not a crash. I notice you have not provide any `flag` value, is that a problem?

Comment: Are you trying to create palette surface (bpp=4 in surface creation)? Start with RGB, it would be much simpler. If not, then your bpp and colour masks are likely to be incorrect.